# Error db._checkNotDeleted when referencing data from Firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a simple ToDoList CRUD web page with React and FireBase (v10.4.0).

When i try to use the ref function to reference the item with a specific ID to remove it, i get the following error:

*Error removing todo: TypeError: db._checkNotDeleted is not a function
at ref (Reference_impl.ts:489:6)*

This is the structure of my ToDos DB in Firebase:

```
{
  "todos": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "value": "Todo1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "value": "Todo2"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is the function implementation:

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = getDatabase(app);
const todosRef = ref(database, "todos");


export const removeTodo = async (todoIdToRemove) => {
  try {
    const todosQuery = query(todosRef, orderByChild("id"), equalTo(todoIdToRemove));
    const snapshot = await get(todosQuery);

    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      const childSnapshot = snapshot.val();
      const keyToRemove = Object.keys(childSnapshot)[0];
      const todoRefToRemove = ref(todosRef, keyToRemove); //line with the error

      await remove(todoRefToRemove);
      console.log(`Removed successfully`);
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error("Error removing todo:", error);
  }

}
```

Note: this is my first time I ask a question here, so please let me know if I am missing something.

Thanks.

I already discarded Firebase configuration and version problems since im able to add items and also checked the documentation but I might just be doing something wrong when looking for the reference to the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a child of a reference use the [`child` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#child), not the `ref` function.

So:

```
const todoRefToRemove = child(todosRef, keyToRemove);
```